# Clipboard warning with python win32com

Tags: python, docx, win32com

How to skip this warning when close doc file opened with python win32com.client :

I am trying to merge multiple docx files and that is okay, but when i close the file shows the next warning.

[Alert message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsUpO.png)

```
def merge_docx1(files, final_docx):
# Start word application
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")
word.DisplayAlerts = False
word.Visible = True

# New blank document
new_document = word.Documents.Add()
for fn in files:
    # Open each file to be merged, copy the contents to the clipboard, and then close the file
    fn = abspath(fn)
    temp_document = word.Documents.Open(fn)
    word.Selection.WholeStory()
    word.Selection.Copy()
    temp_document.Close()
    # Paste to the end of the new document
    new_document.Range()
    word.Selection.Delete()
    word.Application.CutCopyMode = False

    word.Selection.Paste()
    #word.Selection.PasteSpecial(Paste = -4163, Operation = win32.constants.xlNone, SkipBlanks = False, Transpose=False)
    word.Application.CutCopyMode = False

# Save the final file and close the Word application
new_document.SaveAs(final_docx)    
word.Application.CutCopyMode = False
word.Application.CutCopyMode = new_document

word.DisplayAlerts = False
new_document.Close(False)
word.DisplayAlerts = True
```

I tried DisplayAlerts = False and Application.CutCopyMode = False in multiple locations.

Solved Just add, before close file.

```
clip.OpenClipboard()
clip.EmptyClipboard()
clip.CloseClipboard()
```

Comment: I just change and add this:
`clip.OpenClipboard()`  `clip.EmptyClipboard()` and  `clip.CloseClipboard()` before close the file.